# Can mapbox take a variable as a paint property value?

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

So let us imagine that I have this zoom event that update the current value of my zoom on the map:

```
var map_zoom = 8
//Some more code to set up the map
map.on('zoom', function() {
        map_zoom = map.getZoom();
}
```

Now if I have a layer that draws circle like this:

```
map.addLayer({
        'id': 'population',
        'type': 'circle',
        'source': 'data',
        'paint': {
            'circle-radius': map_zoom,
            'circle-color': 'rgba(252,141,98,1)'

});
```

And an other layer that draws circle like this:

```
map.addLayer({
            'id': 'population',
            'type': 'circle',
            'source': 'data',
            'paint': {
                'circle-color': 'rgba(252,141,98,1)'

    });
```

What would be the difference between these two? I have added on my sample code a onClick event to get the paint properties of individual circles, but it seems that in both cases the `'circle-radius'` is a fixed value. That is to say, even in my first case where I set it as depending on the variable that is updated with each zoom level, its value is fixed, even at different zoom levels. Is that normal?

Are mapbox's expressions the only way to modify dynamically a value for a layer or some paint properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the behavior of the paint properties through changing the properties of the features (change source) or using the [`setPaintProperty`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setpaintproperty) method:

```
map.on('zoom', function() {
  var map_zoom = map.getZoom() * 5;
  map.setPaintProperty('total', 'circle-radius', map_zoom);
})
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/pdoa7kLw/ ]

Comment: Totally works thanks! Do you know what the complexity of this function is? Does it go through each individual points to set the property? In other words, if I had to change a property once I reach a specific zoom level and not change it afterwords, should I check whether the change has been made, or can I skip the test?

Comment: @LBes Sorry, but I did not understand - can you clarify your question?

Comment: If I have n elements in my layer's source, will that do n operations to modify the property for the n elements in there?

Comment: Nevermind I tested with a randomly generated 2M points and it doesn't seem to be slower than with a 1000 points only. So I suppose that the complexity is not O(n) :). Thanks again for a great answer.